# Add Colorfilter to Image when onTap fires

Tags: flutter, dart

i got a GridView with some Images. I want the images to apply the ColorFilter if the GestureDetector detects an onTap event. I got this for the whole imageList but i want only the clicked images to apply the ColorFilter. Is there a way?

```dart
    ColorFilter getColorFilter (index) {
      if(activeImages[index]) {
        return ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop);
      }
        return null;
    }

GridView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: imageList.length,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,childAspectRatio: 1.32, mainAxisSpacing: 5.0),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {_onTap(index);},
            child: Container(
              height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: new AssetImage(imageList[index]),
                    colorFilter: getColorFilter(index),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(15)
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          );
         },
      )
```

edit:

```dart
void _onTap(index) {
    setState(() {
        activeImages[index] = !activeImages[index];
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll need a separate index for each image.

Comment: i am working with different indices. Therefore i got a List of bools (activeImages). In my _onTap i set activeImages true/false for the given index